# A quiz question based on finding sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

This question was asked in my  analysis quiz and I had  no clue in the exam how it could be solved.So, I am asking here .

> Find the sum of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2} {2^{n} } $ .

Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Start with the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n=(1-r)^{-1}$

Comment: @Integrand, do you mean, using r=1/2?

Comment: Answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955758/42969,  and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/593996/42969, and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338852/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%7D%20%7B2%5E%7Bn%7D%20%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^n} = \frac{2}{2-x}.$$
Taking the derivative, we see that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^n} = \frac{2}{(2-x)^2}.$$
Multiplying by $x$ and taking the derivative once more, we see that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 x^{n-1}}{2^n} = \frac{4+2x}{(2-x)^3}.$$
Lastly, plugging in $x=1$ gives that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 6.$$